# Ubuntu 20.04, Kernel 5.4.0-45-generic update, NVIDIA failed

Tags: nvidia

With the kernel 5.4.0-45-generic update, NVIDIA Cuda kit for Ubuntu 20.04 fails.  I reverted back to 5.4.0-42.

Comment: What version of CUDA, what version Nvidia drivers, and how did you install them.  Just ran the update for 5.4.0-45 and my CUDA 10.2dr/10.1rt samples run fine with the nvidia 440 drivers.

Comment: Driver Version: 450.51.05    CUDA Version 11.0.207
 Directly from Nvidia, not the repositories.   I just realized 11.0.3 is out, I'll try it.

Comment: I just upgraded to 450.451.06 and 11.03, same problem.  I am guessing Nvidia will update driver and CUDA soon.

Comment: I have a similar problem, kernel 5.4.0-45-generic incompatible with NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1660 Ti, not working at all in Ubuntu 20.04, somebody has any idea about what to do?

Comment: Did you perhaps change the system default compiler version?  CUDA tends to require a (newer/older) compiler version, and if you just make that version the default, the next time you update the kernel, the video driver compile fails, and .... Put the different compiler  or its links in the cuda/bin, so the kernel updates don't get zorched.

Comment: I tried CUDA to 11.1, still didn't work.  Stuck at kernel 5.4.0-42

Comment: Currently working with 11.2.1.  Note: I got myself in a situation where I couldn't use kernel 5.4.0-45, so I went back to previous version.   But, updating CUDA from the older version never led to success.  I realized I had to go to latest kernel version to a lower level runlevel without desktop and then install CUDA 11.2.1, then reboot back to higher runlevel.